# Can't call method "headers" on an undefined value at C:/Perl/site/lib/Net/Stomp. pm line 122

Tags: perl, stomp

I am trying to send EMS message from Perl to queue running in the EMS server. I'm using STOMP module to connect to EMS queue for sending message. Here is my code -

JMSQUEUE.pl:

```
use Net::Stomp;
use Net::Stomp::Frame;
my $stomp = Net::Stomp->new( { hostname => 'localhost', port => '7222' } );
$stomp->connect( { login => 'admin', passcode => '' } );
$stomp->send( { destination => '/queue/pradeepexp', body => 'test message' } );
$stomp->disconnect;
```

and in my module - STOMP.PM:

```
sub connect {
    my ( $self, $conf ) = @_;

    my $frame =
      Net::Stomp::Frame->new( { command => 'CONNECT', headers => $conf } );
    $self->send_frame($frame);
    $frame = $self->receive_frame;

    # Setting initial values for session id, as given from
    # the stomp server
    $self->session_id( $frame->headers->{session} );
    $self->_connect_headers($conf);

    return $frame;
}
```

Any settings I need to do before calling connect?

Comment: What is `STOMP.pm`? Something you wrote yourself or is it really `Stomp.pm` containing the package `Net::Stomp`?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with sending messages from **Perl** to **ApacheMQ**.
(Perl + Net-Stomp-0.45 + apache-activemq-5.8)

It was just a little mistake.
It is important to set the correct *transportConnectors* in this file *harddisk\apache-activemq-5.8\conf\activemq.xml*.

```
<transportConnectors>
   <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://localhost:61616"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

After that it works fine :D
For more information: http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html

Maybe there are similar files in EMS.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the Stomp library receives an invalid (or no) response from the message broker.

Try to telnet to the message broker and see if it speaks Stomp at all.

Comment: I am using EMS Server that is running at localhost 7222 so what to telnet and see can u please explain

Comment: Just ``telnet localhost 7222`` and write a ``CONNECT`` message manually. The specification is here: http://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.1.html#Connecting

Comment: But for starters, see if you get a connection at all when you run ``telnet localhost 7222``.

Comment: I did as you mentioned above telnet localhost 7222 ....... telnet window opened but if i press any button on that window its exiting from telnet

Comment: and one more thing i downloaded stomp module through ppm tool after that do i need to download or set anything else

Comment: The module should work out of the box as you tried. But the point I'm trying to make is that you're probably talking the wrong protocol. Port 7222 is standard for JMS messages (*not Stomp*!). Try the default Stomp port in stead - 61613.

Comment: I am getting the below  thing                                 C:\Documents and Settings\pkn\Desktop>telnet localhost 61613
Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 61613:
Connect failed

Comment: do i need to install stomp server or anything like that                 if yes can u guide me what to do ?

Comment: You probably don't have Stomp running. It's out of scope to help you to install and set it up here. I suggest you ask at serverfault.com or a product support forum for EMS.